# How to properly use Common Lisp's multiple-value-bind and handler-case on this HTTP-request interface?

Tags: http, error-handling, common-lisp, multiple-value

I am using SBCL, Emacs, and Slime. In addition, I am using the library [Dexador](https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador).

Dexador documentation provides an example on how to handle failed HTTP requests.

From the official documentation, it says:

```lisp
;; Handles 400 bad request
(handler-case (dex:get "http://lisp.org")
  (dex:http-request-bad-request ()
    ;; Runs when 400 bad request returned
    )
  (dex:http-request-failed (e)
    ;; For other 4xx or 5xx
    (format *error-output* "The server returned ~D" (dex:response-status e))))
```

Thus, I tried the following. It must be highlighted that this is part of a major system, so I am simplifying it as:

```lisp
;;Good source to test errors:  https://httpstat.us/ 

(defun my-get (final-url) 
  (let* ((status-code)
         (response)
         (response-and-status (multiple-value-bind (response status-code) 
                                  (handler-case (dex:get final-url)
                                    (dex:http-request-bad-request ()
                                      (progn
                                        (setf status-code
                                              "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status.")
                                        (setf response nil)))
                                    (dex:http-request-failed (e)
                                      (progn
                                        (setf status-code
                                              (format nil
                                                      "The server returned a failed request of ~a status."
                                                      (dex:response-status e)))
                                        (setf response nil))))
                                (list response status-code))))
    (list response-and-status response status-code)))
```

My code output is **close** to what I want. But **I do not understand** it is output.

When the HTTP request is successful, this is the output:

```lisp
CL-USER> (my-get "http://www.paulgraham.com")

(("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
<html><script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
 <!-- 
... big HTML omitted...
</script>
</html>"
  200)
 NIL NIL)
```

I was expecting (or wished) the output to be something like: `'(("big html" 200) "big html" 200)`.

But, things happen to be even weirder when the HTTP request fails. For instance:

```lisp
CL-USER> (my-get "https://httpstat.us/400")

((NIL NIL) NIL
 "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status.")
```

I was expecting: `'((NIL "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status.") NIL "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status.")`

Or:

```lisp
CL-USER> (my-get "https://httpstat.us/425")
((NIL NIL) NIL "The server returned a failed request of 425 status.")
```

Again, I was expecting: `((NIL "The server returned a failed request of 425 status.") NIL "The server returned a failed request of 425 status.")`

I am afraid there is a **variable overshadowing** problem happening - not sure, though.

How can I create a function so that I can **safely** store in variables the response and the status-code independent of being a failed or successful request?

If the request is successful, I have `("html" 200)`. If it fails, it would be: `(nil 400)` or other number `(nil 425)` - depending on the error message.

Comment: Your MVB declares `response` and `status-code` variables, for its scope only, which override the `let*` declaration.

Comment: You don't need `progn` inside the error handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you failed to understand how `multiple-value-bind`, `handler-case`, and `let*` work. (Probably also `setf` and `progn`.)

#### TLDR

Quick fix:

```lisp
(defun my-get (final-url)
  (let* ((status-code)
     (response)
     (response-and-status
       (multiple-value-bind (bresponse bstatus-code)
           (handler-case (dex:get final-url)
         (dex:http-request-bad-request ()
           (values nil
               "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status."))
         (dex:http-request-failed (e)
           (values nil
               (format nil "The server returned a failed request of ~a status." (dex:response-status e)))))
         (list (setf response bresponse)
               (setf status-code bstatus-code)))))
    (list response-and-status response status-code)))
```

Output:

```lisp
CL-USER> (my-get "http://www.paulgraham.com")
(("big html" 200) "big html" 200)
CL-USER> (my-get "https://httpstat.us/400")
((NIL "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status.") NIL "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status.")
CL-USER> (my-get "https://httpstat.us/425")
((NIL "The server returned a failed request of 425 status.") NIL "The server returned a failed request of 425 status.")
```

#### So, Why Do You Get Your Current Result?

##### Preliminary

For `multiple-value-bind`, it binds multiple values returning from a `values` form into the corresponding variables.

```lisp
CL-USER> (multiple-value-bind (a b)
             nil
           (list a b))
(NIL NIL)
CL-USER> (multiple-value-bind (a b)
             (values 1 2)
           (list a b))
(1 2)
CL-USER> (multiple-value-bind (a b)
             (values 1 2 3 4 5)
           (list a b))
(1 2)
```

For `handler-case`, it returns the value of the expression form when there is no error. When there is an error, it will execute the corresponding error-handling code.

```lisp
CL-USER> (handler-case (values 1 2 3)
            (type-error () 'blah1)
            (error () 'blah2))
1
2
3
CL-USER> (handler-case (signal 'type-error)
            (type-error () 'blah1)
            (error () 'blah2))
BLAH1
CL-USER> (handler-case (signal 'error)
            (type-error () 'blah1)
            (error () 'blah2))
BLAH2
```

For `let*` form, variables are initialised to `nil` if `init-forms` are not provided. Same goes to the `let` form. The parentheses around these variables without init-forms are unneeded. Example:

```lisp
CL-USER> (let* (a b (c 3))
            (list a b c))
(NIL NIL 3)
```

#### Combining These Knowledges

When `dex:get` success (i.e. no error), it returns the values of `dex:get`, which is `(values body status response-headers uri stream)`. With `multiple-value-bind`, your `response-and-status` is bound to the value of `(list response status-code)`, which is `("big html" 200)`.

Since the code in both `dex:http-request-bad-request` and `dex:http-request-failed` will only be executed when `dex:get` failed, both `response` and `status-code` have the initial value `nil`. That's why you get `(("big html" 200) nil nil)` on success.

When `dex:get` failed, both `response` and `status-code` are `setf` to new values. Since `(setf response nil)` mutates the value of `response` **and** returns `nil` (the new value set), and since `progn` returns the value of last form, your `progn` returns `nil` for both error handling cases. That's why your `response-and-status` is bound to `(nil nil)` when failed.

Comment: Hello new contributor with a lot of knowledge o/

Comment: Hi @Ehvince, I'm flattered. I'm here to learn more about CL, same as everyone else =D

Comment: For readers, also read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71917972/how-to-properly-use-common-lisps-multiple-value-bind-and-handler-case-on-this-h/71919202#comment127089066_71917972) from Ehvince

Answer (score 3):

This is an addendum to [zacque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71919202/17026934), which describes the problem and your confusions about `multiple-value-bind` & other things pretty well.

As mentioned in that answer, `dex:get` returns five values: body, status, response-headers, uri, stream.  But it also signals one of various conditions on failure.  So one obvious thing to do is simply have a function which returns the same five values (there's no reason to package some of them into a list), but handles the errors, relying on the handler to return suitable values.  Such a function is terribly simple, and has no assignment.

```
(defun my-get (final-url)
  (handler-case (dex:get final-url)
    (dex:http-request-failed (e)
      ;; These are probably not the right set of values, but if the
      ;; first one is NIL we're basically OK.
      (values nil
              (dex:response-status e)
              e
              (format nil
                      "The server returned a failed request of ~a status."
                      (dex:response-status e))
              nil))))
```

If you really want to package the values up into some structure you can do that, but generally it's easy to just handle multiple values.  For instance a user of this function can now just ignore all but the first value rather than unpacking all sorts of grot, so:

```
(defun my-get-user (url)
  (or (my-get url)
      (error "oops")))
```